# How to add third party Template in my existing Android Project?

Tags: java, android, xml

I Have a Running project in android studio, I want to add one template downloaded from wsdesign.in. How to do it, weather I have to add the all files manually one by one or we have any integration option in Android Studio?
If it is possible please suggest some examples or tutorials.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download Project first of all then extract after that you can see inside folder src inside two folder res and java, you can copy which file you need ctrl+c and ctrl+v hope it works, comment please is not work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it means that i have to add the resources manually whatever is inside the template ?

Comment: yes which part like you need fully xml or or any view copy and paste and same thing for java